# Auto-add PackageReferences to NuGet package

Tags: c#, dependencies, package, nuget

In my project I reference some packages with `PackageReference` like that:

[image: My PackageReference]

But, if I run pack command, it doesn't include them unless I manually add them to `.nuspec` file.

[image: Adding references to nuspec file]

I want to automatically add packages from `PackageReference` in my C# project to NuGet packages.

I pack my project using `nuget pack ProjectFile` on Build or manually.

Current nuspec with dependencies:

[image: NuSpec with dependencies]

P.S. *AFAIK references from `packages.config` are automatically added, but I don't want to use this file. I want to use `PackageReferences` instead.*

Comment: How do you generate your nuget?

Comment: Added to description. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you don't need .nuspec file anymore. All information you can specify in csproj file like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageId>BinaryTree</PackageId>
    <Version>5.1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>RMarusyk</Authors>
    <Description>Simple Binary Tree implementation</Description>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/Marusyk/BinaryTree</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageTags>binarytree</PackageTags>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then I've added this line into csproj.

```
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

To build it I use:

```
dotnet build -c Release src/Solution.sln
dotnet pack -c Release src/Solution.sln
dotnet nuget push ..
```

It works in my case without define any dependencies

Comment: Thanks. Is there a public list of all available tags for NuGet for csproj?

Comment: yes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties

Comment: Does not work, I use nuget pack and nothing is got from the csproject

Comment: Sorry, sure. It doesn't take any info from csproj (To test I set RequireLicenseAcc. to true, and nothing changed in nuspec + no references from PackageReference).

Comment: Did you run `nuget pack` or `dotnet pack`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196385/discussion-between-iv-misticos-and-roman-marusyk).

Comment: It's nice when someone other than me points out that nuspec files are no longer needed :)  About using `GeneratePackageOnBuild`, this will slow down your code-build-debug cycle, as it will generate the package on every build, even when you don't intend on pushing or testing the package. `dotnet pack` on a solution will pack all projects in the solution that [are packable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#ispackable).